# Apache HTTP Not Working When SSL Enabled

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl

I've got a very bizarre problem in that after enabling SSL support in Apache I'm only able to access my site via SSL and not through http as well.

I can confirm that Apache is definitely listening on both ports 80 and 443 (accdording to netstat). Additionally the Apache access logs are showing the requests - it's just that going in through http results in a timeout and I'm never actually able to reach the content. Like I said going through https works.

Here is my httpd.conf:
http://pastebin.com/kG2dPjJ2

and here is my httpd-ssl.conf:
http://pastebin.com/thqvjgGJ

Can anyone spot any issues with those configurations? or Have any suggestion at all?

I've searched and searched but there appear to be very few people who have experienced the same.

Also worth mentioning that I did a comparision between those configurations and those of a working set up and I couldn't spot anything.

Comment: See if you get any error logs.

Comment: Nothing in the logs I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You are running two separate httpd instances, which are both trying to use the same logfiles. That means that one of them will be unable to write to the file, and that instance will be hanging.

If you want to use the same file for both of them, you should run them in the same instance, using `VirtualHost` to separate SSL from non-SSL. Otherwise, use separate log files.

#### EDIT

Also, your httpd.conf for port 80 contains the line:

```
Include /storage/.xbmc/userdata/addon_data/service.web.lamp/srvroot/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

This means that you're first doing most of the things in your httpd.conf up to that `Include`-line. Then you're doing all of the things in httpd-ssl.conf, and after that you're doing all the things from your httpd.conf that are below that `Include`-line. This is very unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not correct the problem, however I did notice that I'm getting dual entries in the log files for everything SSL related as httpd starts up. It's almost like it's trying to use port 80 for SSL and then that's immediately getting stolen by 443.

Comment: @dominic7il I think I found the issue now and have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apache can show symptoms like these, particularly headers being sent but no data, if your system has broken kernel sendfile support. It's worth experimentally adding

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

to your config.

Answer (score -1):

In order to have a "site" You need a VHOST (virtual host).

The configuration files provided have only a vhost for SSL (443). I am not sure what you are attempting to achieve but adding a section similar to the following (in httpd.conf) will help:

`<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "/some/place"
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAdmin dominic@dcrdev.com
    ErrorLog "/some/place/for/logs/error"
    TransferLog "/some/place/for/logs/transfer"
    CustomLog "/some/place/for/logs/access"
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: A virtual host is only required when you want to serve more than one site with different hostnames, content and/or logs.

Comment: Http content should be getting served up by the global document root shouldn't it? That's why I've not configured a virtual host for http connections.

Comment: @dominic7il Correct - if all you've got is one site for your apache instance, then you don't need a VirtualHost.